# Помогите с реализацией асинхроннасти

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, бот, discord.py

допустим есть дискорд бот
и в нем есть функция:

```
@bot.command()
async def test(ctx):
    while True:
        await ctx.send(f"TEST")
        sleep(30)
```

если запустить данный код в 1 канале 1 раз, то все будет хорошо, но если сразу в двух каналах запустить данный код, то ничего работать не будет, бот попросту игнорирует то что во 2 канале я написал точно такую же команду

НУЖНО:
чтоб при написании команды, создавался отдельный поток, в котором будет выполняться данная команда

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вероятно, проблема вовсе не в этом, тем более, что бот все равно не будет работать ни в каком потоке, кроме главного.

Здесь проблема в том, что у вас выставлена большая задержка - 30 секунд. И эта задержка в асинхронной функции реализована через не асинхронную функцию `time.sleep()`. Из-за этого, при большом количестве вызовов весь код стопится до тех пор, пока не пройдет последняя задержка из вызванных.

---

Решением здесь будет переход на асинхронную задержку из модуля `asyncio`:

```
from asyncio import sleep
```

```py
@bot.command()
async def test(ctx):
    while True:
        await ctx.send(f"TEST")
        await sleep(30)
```

---

Некоторые действия, требующие выделения в другую функцию, можно выделить при помощи функции `asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe()`, которая первым аргументом принимает асинхронную функцию, а вторым текущий поток бота:

```py
async def send_test(context):
    while True:
        await context.send(f"TEST")
        await asyncio.sleep(30)

@bot.command()
async def test(ctx):
    asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(send_test(ctx), bot.loop)
```

Comment: дело не в одном лишь слипе, данный код я поставил как пример, мне нужно чтоб каждая команда запускалась в новом потоке, ибо есть долгосрочные задачи

Comment: Это нужно было сразу же указывать в тексте вопроса. Я дополнил ответ, но, так или иначе, я уже написал, что бот не будет работать ни в каком другом потоке, кроме главного. Асинхронные функции для того и сделаны, чтобы запускать несколько экземпляров в одном потоке. Выделения в отдельную функцию, как в дополнении к ответу, имеет смысл использовать только когда вам нужно выполнять несколько действий параллельно, всего при одном вызове команды в чате

Comment: @Selasi в таком виде вас устроит ответ?

Comment: да, меня полностью устраивает ваш ответ.